# jQueryUI Accordion - how do I expand a single content pane?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

When I click a content header in my accordion, all the content panes are opened rather than just the one I click on.

http://jsfiddle.net/es7g1cvk/

```
var allPanels = $('ul.accordion-content').hide();

    $('.accounts').click(function() {
        console.log('click')
        allPanels.slideUp();

        if($('.accordion-content').is(':hidden')) {
            console.log('hidden')

            $(".accordion-content").slideDown();
        }

        return false;
    });
```

How can I open a single content pane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to open all ".accordion-content" items, but u need to open just container inside of clicked div.
try this:

```
    var content = $(this).find('.accordion-content');
    if(content.is(':hidden')) {
        console.log('hidden')

        content.slideDown();
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/es7g1cvk/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
var allPanels = $('ul.accordion-content').hide();

$('li').click(function() {
    var a =  $(this).find('.accordion-content');

    allPanels.slideUp();

    if($('.accordion-content').is(':hidden')) {


        $(a).slideDown();
    }

    return false;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/es7g1cvk/4/)